# Find the sum of the series $1+\frac12 z^2+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}z^4+....$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series

Find the sum of the series $1+\frac12 z^2+\frac{1\cdot3}{2\cdot4}z^4+....$. We can rewrite n-th term as $a_n=\frac{(n-1)(n-3)\cdot...\cdot1}{n(n-2)\cdot..\cdot2}z^n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}\cdot(n!)^2}z^n$. But I don't know what should I do now. Consider the ratio $|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$?

Comment: Is this a binomial series?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown as it appears, if there alternated the sign, then I know that it would be $\sqrt{(1+z)}$

Comment: I don't think your n th term is correct,  check for $n=1$

Comment: @Manthanein We cac rewrite our series as $1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(2k)!}{2^{2k}\cdot(k!)^2}z^k $. Then it's true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your series is$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\binom{-\frac12}nz^{2n}$$and therefore its sum is $(1-z^2)^{-\frac12}$, when $|z|<1$.

Comment: Thanks! By Cauchy–Hadamard theorem we got that our series is converge when $|z|<1$?

Comment: @user1223 Yes. That's how I would do it.

Comment: Can you explain how to see this representation?

Comment: @user1223 Since$$(1+z)^{-\frac12}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-\frac12}nz^n,$$putting $-z^2$ instead of $z$ you get your series.

Comment: @VonNeumann: $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$. Plug in $n=-\frac12$. This is the way the coefficients are defined in the [generalized binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton's_generalized_binomial_theorem).

Answer (score 2):

Another approach (same origin as the other answer, but starting from a well-known formula): we have, for a real $z$ s. t. $|z|<1$,
$$\arcsin z=z+\frac12\frac{z^3}3+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\frac{z^5}5+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\frac{z^7}7+\dotsm, $$
whence
$$(\arcsin z)'=\frac1{\sqrt{1-z^2\strut}}=1+\frac12z^2+\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}z^4+\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}z^6+\dotsm. $$
The radius of convergence, of course, is $1$.

Comment: Great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Due to De Moivre's formula $\cos\theta=\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}$, the binomial theorem and the orthogonality relation $\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{ni\theta}e^{-mi\theta}\,d\theta=2\pi\delta(m,n)$ we have
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\left(\cos\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta = 2\pi\frac{(2n)!}{4^n n!^2}\tag{1}$$
for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, hence
$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{z^n}{4^n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1-z\cos^2\theta}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{1-z\cos^2\theta}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{(1-z)+u^2}\tag{2}$$
and $\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{z^n}{4^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}$ holds for any $z\in(-1,1)$.
 As an interesting consequence, by squaring both sides we get
$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\qquad \sum_{m=0}^{n}\binom{2m}{m}\binom{2n-2m}{n-m}=4^n.\tag{3} $$
You may also go in the opposite direction: a combinatorial proof of $(3)$ leads to $\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{z^n}{4^n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z}}$ almost immediately.